# Script# Call a Rest Service

Tags: script#

I tried to use this code in SCript#

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(string.Concat("http://localhost:49175/GetProjects")));
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
  using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(tmp);
  }
}
```

But I have this error:

> Error 3 The assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll' is not a valid script assembly.

Is it the way to use `System.Net`, `System.IO.StreamReader` and `Newtonsoft.Json` in Script#? If it is impossible, how can I change the code?

Comment: You cannot reference .NET assemblies in Script#. Also, S# is only compatible with the C# 2.0 spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem in this way

```
string tfsIntegration = string.Format(string.Concat("http://localhost:49175"));

System.Net.XmlHttpRequest getProjectRequest = new System.Net.XmlHttpRequest();

getProjectRequest.Open("GET", tfsIntegration + "/GetProjects", false);
getProjectRequest.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
getProjectRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
getProjectRequest.SetRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");            
getProjectRequest.Send(null);
```